# Writing out group_by with length > 1 to individual text files in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-management

Apologies, I am still getting acquainted with the world of dplyr and data.table, and trying to figure out its full capabilities!

I have a dataset where I am interested in grouping on a specific variable (locus):

```
DF <- structure(list(Gene = c("GeneA", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneD", "GeneE"), 
                Locus = c("1","2","2","3","3"),
                Chromosome = c("1","1","1","1","1"),
                Start = c("100","500","600","1000","1500"),
                Stop = c("200","550","700","1400","1750")),
                .Names = c("Gene","Locus","Chromosome","Start","Stop"), 
                row.names = c(NA, 5L), 
                class = "data.frame")

> DF
   Gene Locus Chromosome Start Stop
GeneA     1          1   100  200
GeneB     2          1   500  550
GeneC     2          1   600  700
GeneD     3          1  1000 1400
GeneE     3          1  1500 1750
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to write out "per locus" files containing the values from the Gene, Chromosome, Start, Stop columns in instances where there are more than one value for the locus column. So Locus==1 would have no text file written out, but the values in the Gene column for Locus==2 and Locus==3 would be written to individual files?
e.g.

```
<loc2.txt>
   Gene Chromosome Start Stop
GeneB           1   500  550
GeneC           1   600  700

<loc3.txt>
   Gene Chromosome Start Stop
GeneD           1  1000 1400
GeneE           1  1500 1750
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your `structure` seems to be missing a bracket at the end, and doesn't seem to match up with your example output. Could you edit your question or clarify this?

Comment: To add to the above - you may have a slight typo - in ```DF```, the corresponding locus for GeneC is 3 (row 3), but in DF2 it is 2. Is that value supposed to be 2 or 3?

Comment: Fixed! Apologies, this is what I get for tweaking the data between the question creation page and the R terminal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
newDF <- DF %>%
  group_by(Locus) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  nest_by()
newDF
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# # Rowwise:  Locus
#   Locus               data
#   <chr> <list<tbl_df[,4]>>
# 1 2                [2 x 4]
# 2 3                [2 x 4]
mapply(function(x, nm) write.csv(x, nm),
       newDF$data, paste0("loc", newDF$Locus, ".csv"))
# [[1]]
# NULL
# [[2]]
# NULL
```

The files are created in the current directory. You can safely ignore the `NULL` output from `mapply`.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
newDT <- DT[, .SD[.N > 1, .(data = list(.SD))], by = Locus]
newDT
#     Locus              data
#    <char>            <list>
# 1:      2 <data.table[2x4]>
# 2:      3 <data.table[2x4]>
mapply(function(x, nm) write.csv(x, nm),
       newDF$data, paste0("loc", newDF$Locus, ".csv"))
```

Comment: Ahh amazing, thank you! Sorry to try and pry even further intel, but the data frame I am applying this to actually has several columns that I'm wanting to write out (Gene, Chromosome, Start, Stop). Is there a way of modifying this so that it isn't only extracting one variable? As beyond this current situation, it would be really useful to know how to grab more than just the gene column. Thanks again!

Comment: You said to write the lines to a text file. Do you instead mean to write the `data.frame` to CSV or such? Please edit your original question with more relevant sample data, please.

Comment: I have failed in my initial question by keeping my example overly simplistic but then minimizing the generalizability! I shall update. Apologies.

Comment: There we go! This would have been the correct question to ask, but thank you very much for your original response, as that will be amazingly useful for other tasks as I go through the dpylr and data.table exploration journey! Sorry for messing up the first time.

Comment: See my edit. The changes are not significant, so is still rather generalizable as needed. It *can* be code-golfed if interested, but I broke out the anon-func in `mapply` a little for clarity.

Comment: Amazing! I have just tried this and tweaked it a bit so that it read out as a .txt with tab separation (as that is what the software for the next step takes as input). The stage where it collapses the whole data frame into a variable is really cool! Thank you so much. Also, not to be too naive, but what is "code-golfed"?

Comment: In general, code-golf is shortening code to the fewest characters possible. There's even https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. Sometimes it produces very readable code, all-too-often it over-reduces to the point of obfuscation and obscurity, using language-specific tricks that are counter-intuitive, rarely-known, or "features" (bugs) in the parsers. (In the end ... unimportant for this answer :-)

Comment: Sorry about my mixup between `write.csv` and `write.table`. Otherwise, did the answer resolve your question?

Comment: Ah! Amazing! Thank you, I shall check out that codegolf link. I do love stuff like that (I use awk quite a bit for data management, and am always amazed at how short you can get the code). But if it is code I am sharing with others, I tend to err on the side of being verbose just so they know what on earth I am talking about haha. Thanks again for all your help, it is really appreciated :D